# Swift: Hidden navigation bar appears when tap occurs in view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

### Introduction

I'm creating a simple app in with the `RootViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I have a `UIView` subclass "landscapeView" with a `UICollectionView` in it that fills the view. "landscapeView" is hidden in portrait and displayed in landscape device orientation.

### Issue

When the device is rotated to a landscape orientation I hide the navigationBar and the portrait table view "rootTableView", while showing the "landscapeView". However, the navigationBar appears when I tap the screen in landscape orientation. I can't figure out how to disable this tap to show thing. (I have `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false, its setup to default in storyboard).

Clarification: hiding the navigation bar works perfectly depending on device orientation.

### Question

*How can I prevent the navigationBar from appearing when the screen is tapped in landscape orientation?*

### Code

1. `viewWillTransition()` in the "RootViewController"

   ```
   private let landscapeView = LandscapeView(frame: .zero)
   private let rootTableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)

   override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
       super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)   

       var isLandscape = true
       switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
       case .landscapeLeft:
           navigationController?.navigationItem.searchController?.accessibilityElementsHidden = true

           isLandscape = true
       case .landscapeRight:

           navigationController?.navigationItem.searchController?.accessibilityElementsHidden = true

           isLandscape = true
       case .portrait, .portraitUpsideDown, .faceUp, .faceDown, .unknown:

           isLandscape = false
         navigationController?.navigationItem.searchController?.accessibilityElementsHidden = false

       default:
           break
       }

       if isLandscape {
           navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
           self.landscapeView.isHidden = false

           // This simply tells the "landscapeView" to layoutSubviews() and reloadData() for the collectionView within.
           landscapeViewDelegate?.landscapeViewWillAppear(inDarkMode: inDarkMode)
       }
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, options: .layoutSubviews, animations: {
           // This is a tableView displayed in portrait mode.
           self.rootTableView.alpha = isLandscape ? 0 : 1 
           self.landscapeView.alpha = isLandscape ? 1 : 0
       }) { (success) in
           if isLandscape == false {
               self.landscapeView.isHidden = true
                self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
           }
           return
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Try this !! lanscapeView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav Thanks for commenting. That removes the gestures for the `UICollectionView` within the "landscapeView", however the navigationController still appears when I tap the landscapeView.

Comment: Now you want to hide the navigation bar?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav Yes, I want to hide the navigation bar when the device is in landscape orientation, which works perfectly. However if I tap the screen when in landscape orientation the navigation bar appears.

Comment: Check with the breakpoint might be you change the flag of navigation bar hidden false? or your isLandscape flag change when you tapped the screen?

Comment: @theoadahl Do you want to remove the "tap to show/hide bars" completely? Or just disable it when in landscape?

Comment: @AndréSlotta I have the tap to show/hide set to false. Well, I want the navigationBar to show in portrait and be hidden in landscape, no matter what the user does.

Comment: @theoadahl Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you checked `Hide Bars When Vertically Compact` for your navigation controller in the storyboard. This property brings that tap behaviour with it:

> When the value of this property is true, the navigation controller
>   hides its navigation bar and toolbar when it transitions to a
>   vertically compact environment. Upon returning to a vertically regular
>   environment, the navigation controller automatically shows both bars
>   again. In addition, unhandled taps in the content area cause the
>   navigation controller to show both bars again. The default value of
>   this property is false.

You can uncheck that property since you take care of showing and hiding the navigation bar in the `viewWillTransition` method yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it does not address the "show on tap" issue, the navigation bar still appears on tap. The `hidesBarsOnTap` does not prevent the navigation bar from appearing upon tap, it appears to only affect dismissal of the navigation bar. Did that work for you?

Comment: I created a simple demonstration project and uploaded it to GitHub, which illustrates the issue. Please see the edit in my question for a link.

Comment: @theoadahl Updated my answer.

Comment: Glad I could help.